# Programmatically exporting BizTalk server configuration

Tags: cmd, biztalk

We could programmatically import BizTalk server configuration using the following command :

```
<BizTalk path>configuration.exe /s config.xml
```

However, how to export the configuration using command line?

Comment: Can you describe a bit why you're trying to do this?  It doesn't seem like a very commonly useful action. :(

Comment: You are correct, BTSTask ExportSettings exports the settings, not the configuration. I deleted my answer. Can you explain why do you need to export the configuration? Maybe is posible with other actions.

Comment: Hi , thanks a lot for your comments.Yep, it may not be so frequent to export the configuration.However we want to automate this fubctionality so we require command line option for this.Please let me know if there is any way .While import is possible why export is not possible? :)

Comment: But why?  Unless you have a tool that automatically changes settings, there is no feasible scenario where you would need to automatically export settings.  What I'm saying is, you'd spend more time automating this than it would ever save you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion.I agreed with your point that there is no dynamic/automated configuration.But is that the very reason Bizstalk does not support automated export? Is it intentionally left out? Any light on this can help us evaluate whether to proceed with automation.However , I agree with you that we spend more time automating that just simply exporting from UI.

Comment: @vayukumaran It doesn't exist after 13 years because no one has ever asked for it.  There is/was a bug in configuration import for at least 10 years that apparently no one noticed.  This strongly suggests there are no practical use cases for this feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BizTalk PowerShell extension to do this. They come on the BizTalk CD as of 2013 I believe. On the BizTalk 2016 CD they are under:
`<drive-letter>:\BizTalk Server\MSI\Program Files\SDK\Utilities\PowerShell`

Once installed, from Powershell you can navigate the BizTalk server like it's a filesystem:

```
PS BizTalk:\> cd .\Applications
PS BizTalk:\Applications> Export-Bindings -Path <my-application-name> -Destination c:\temp\myAppBindings.xml
```

This will export the bindings to a destination of your choosing. You could even set up some kind of scheduled task to run the PS script if desired.